# How to get Multiselect attribute admin value in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, admin-panel, multiselect-attribute

I am trying to get admin value in multiselect but I am not able to get this can anybody suggest?[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $eavData;

public function __construct(
    ...............................................
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavData,
    ...............................................
) {
    ...............................................
    $this->eavData = $eavData;
    ...............................................
}

...............................................
...............................................

public function getAdminValue()
{
    echo "<pre>";
    $attribute = $this->eavData->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'Your Attribute Code Here')->setStoreId(0);
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($options as $existingOption) {
        echo $existingOption['label']."<br/>";
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
}
```